# Equivelent solutions to second order ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have worked out the solution to an ODE using two methods, with solutions as follows:
$$A e^{-5t} + B e^{3t}$$
$$\text {and}$$
$$A\begin{pmatrix} \;1 \\ {-5} \end{pmatrix} e^{-5t}+B\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix} e^{3t}$$

Does the second give more information? I am not sure how to interpret the second solution. I believe that the second solution is actually two separate solutions $y$ along each line. Is that correct? Which would also make sense given that the first equation is along the top line of the second

Comment: Ar those `A, B` constants? Or they are matrices just in the second?

Comment: @BabakS. They are constants

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the solution to an ODE (say $\ddot{x} + 2\dot{x} - 15x = 0$) is given by
$$x(t) = Ae^{-5t} + Be^{3t}.$$
Notice that when you differentiate this you get
$$\dot{x}(t) = -5Ae^{-5t} + 3Be^{3t}$$
which is the second row of your vector solution
$$
\left(\begin{matrix}x\\ \dot{x}\end{matrix}\right)
=A\left(\begin{matrix}\ 1\\ -5\end{matrix}\right)e^{-5t}
+B\left(\begin{matrix}1\\ 3\end{matrix}\right)e^{3t}.
$$
As for which gives more information; the information is there in both. I find the second form more convenient as it has all the things i need for phase plane analysis.

Comment: So my second is actually $\begin{pmatrix} y(t) \\y'(t) \end{pmatrix} = \dots$

Comment: Yep, that's correct.